# Excel Setting a variable to be a

Tags: vba, excel, variables, vbscript

I have like 3 columns in a spreadsheet. 
They are `Body`, `First Name`, and `Last Name`. For example:

```
Body               First Name                  Last Name
```

`Dear $var etc...      Jon                         Doe`
`Dear $var etc...      Jane                        Doe`

What I want is for `$var` to be the concatenation with a space of the first name on current row plus a space plus the last name on the same row.

Basically the body in the end should be appear to be `"Dear Jon Doe"`  and `"Dear Jane Doe"`. I hope I made myself clear enough. Please ask questions for further clarification.

Comment: Do you need to use VBA? This seems like a good opportunity to use [=CONCATENATE](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your first row is row 2, you'd enter the following worksheet function in A2:

```
="Dear "&B2&" "&C2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim str as string
str = replace(range("A2"), "var$", range("B2") & chr(32) & range("C2"))
'do something with str
```